# Javascript - Undefined attribute in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am attempting to add two attributes to a array of objects so I decided to create a new array of objects from the original one and then set the new attributes. (I realize there are probably be easier ways of doing this.)

My problem is that when I attempt to access an attribute within the new array it is undefined. What is wrong is probably obvious but not to me. Help!

```
var join = [];
for (linksIndex = 0; linksIndex < links.length; ++linksIndex) {
     join.push([{source:links[linksIndex].source,target:links[linksIndex].target, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0}]);
    };

for (joinIndex = 0; joinIndex < join.length; ++joinIndex) {

//   console.log("join in loop");console.log(join); // ok array of objects
//   console.log("join[joinIndex]");console.log(join[joinIndex]); // on object
   console.log("join[joinIndex].source");console.log(join[joinIndex].source); // undefined why?

   for (nodesIndex = 0; nodesIndex < nodes.length; ++nodesIndex) {
      if (nodes[nodesIndex].name == join[joinIndex].source) { 
        join[joinIndex].x1=nodes[nodesIndex].x; // match source 
        join[joinIndex].y1=nodes[nodesIndex].y; // match source
        };  
     if (nodes[nodesIndex].name == join[joinIndex].target) { 
        join[joinIndex].x2=nodes[nodesIndex].x; // match target
        join[joinIndex].y2=nodes[nodesIndex].y; // match target
        } ;   
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing in the array another array with an object!

so if you change it to:

```
join[joinIndex][0].source
```

it will work. But i guess this is not what you want. So change the join.push() to:

```
join.push({
    source: links[linksIndex].source,
    target: links[linksIndex].target,
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
     join.push([{source:links[linksIndex].source,target:links[linksIndex].target, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0}]);
```

To:

```
     join.push({source:links[linksIndex].source,target:links[linksIndex].target, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0});
```

Or use `console.log(join[joinIndex][0].source);//you need to access the array you made`

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing arrays containing objects into your `join` array. When you attempt to access `x1` or `x2` in the array, you're getting `undefined`, because the array only has one element at `0` (which is the object you're expecting).

You need to do: `join.push({source:links[linksIndex].source,target:links[linksIndex].target, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0})`

It would be easy to catch this error by using a debugger. I would put a breakpoint on the second loop, and it would be easy to see exactly what `join` contains.